# Is a PairRDD faster than a non-Pair RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

In Spark, operations on the **RDD** (like Map) are applied to the whole RDD while operations on **Pair RDD** are applied on each element in parallel.
I want to know which one is faster for operations on the larger data sets?

Comment: What is ur usecase if you add detail then will get proper answer ,rdd applied on full collection while pair rdd applied only key value pair .

Comment: I am creating RDD of 1,00,000 by 1,00,000 and doing element wise operation on each single row of the RDD in an iterative algorithm where iterations are in millions.

Comment: A PairRDD is an RDD, behaves like an RDD and offers extra methods due to the fact it has a key. A PairRDD isn't faster than a RDD.

Answer (score 1):

No, and there is no such comparison to be made.

What is relevant, is that a pairRDD has more capabilities. E.g. use of a JOIN.